# TypeError: o.promise is not a function while upgrading intel app framework 2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, intel, appframework

while upgrading intel app framework from 2.0 to 2.1, it is throwing an jquery error 'TypeError: o.promise is not a function in jquery'. 
I am using jq.appframework.min.js with jquery-1.11.0.min.js

Comment: Please tell us when this happens. On page load, or when you execute custom code? The show us how you have included it in the page and what your code is.

Comment: It happens on page load. I just included the above given two js in my html page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might be happening because of because of the upgraded jquery version. You need to downgrade it or merge the depreciated functionality.